# R: How to melt data in R where row values become the column labels?

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I have this data

```
   RES  RANK1   RANK2   RANK3   RANK4   RANK5
    1   3   3   5   16  1
    2   3   1   2   5   16
    3   3   5   15  10  1
```

how do i melt the data such that values of RANK1 to RANK5 becomes the variable and RANK1 to RANK5 becomes the value.

The data were gathered by: among the list of (22) items, select the top 5 preferences.

The new data would be analyze as if the answers are multi response.

expected output would be (eg.RES=1)

```
RES 1      2      3        5       10       15     16
1   RANK5         RANK2    RANK3                   RANK4
2   RANK2  RANK3  RANK1    RANK4                   RANK5
3   RANK5         RANK1    RANK2   RANK4    RANK3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... could you provide an example of the output that you would like to have?

Comment: Hi Nico, I editted the question for you to see my expected output. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will neeed to `melt` your data and then `dcast` it. Because you don't have unique values for each combination you need some way to keep all values when you have more than one (as happens here for `RES == 1` and `VALUE == 3`). In this case we just concatenate the values using `paste` with a `collapse` argument:

```
dcast( melt( df , measure = 2:6 ) , RES ~ value , value.var = "variable" , fun = function(x) paste(x,collapse=";") , fill = ""   )
#  RES     1     2           3     5    10    15    16
#1   1 RANK5       RANK1;RANK2 RANK3             RANK4
#2   2 RANK2 RANK3       RANK1 RANK4             RANK5
#3   3 RANK5             RANK1 RANK2 RANK4 RANK3
```

The effect of `melt` using the `RANK*` columns as measure variables is to give us a long dataset with two columns of id variables like so

```
head( melt( df , measure = 2:6 ) )
#  RES variable value
#1   1    RANK1     3
#2   2    RANK1     3
#3   3    RANK1     3
#4   1    RANK2     3
#5   2    RANK2     1
#6   3    RANK2     5
```

Comment: Hi Simon, yes, but its not what i need. I editted my questions for you to see my expected output, Thanks for your help!

Comment: @dixi yes it is... hold on.

Comment: @dixi for value=3 and res=1 you have both rank1 and rank2. How do you decide between them? e.g. you put rank2 in your example.

Comment: i see. probably its just a mistake with the (data) coding, so either rank1 or rank2 is ok.. if its possible to have both rank1,rank2 as the value, it is better.

Comment: Thank you Simon! This is what Im looking for. :-D